# Excel VBA - Select cells based on the value of another cell and then Autosum - Is it possible

Tags: excel, vba

Please can you help

I am trying to use the autosum feature in the highlighted boxes as per the example below (these are shown in yellow for illustration purposes only)

In column A the word "Total" appears and this is the indication that the autosum needs to be used in columns L,M & N

The data in each section varies in length so unfortunately I am not able just to record a macro to achieve this.

I need to use VBA coding, so if you are able to help it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: OTIF Sample Pircute]

Thanks

Regards
 Steve

Comment: Why do you want VBA? Did you try Data > SubTotal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lStartSection As Long

Set ws = Application.Sheets("Sheet1")
lRow = 3
lStartSection = 0

'Loop through the used range in the spreadsheet
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'If we are at the start of a section record the row.
    If lStartSection = 0 And ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
        lStartSection = lRow
    End If

    'Check if we are at the bottom of a section
    If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "Total" Then
        ws.Range("L" & lRow).Value = "=SUM(L" & lStartSection & ":L" & lRow - 1 & ")"
        ws.Range("M" & lRow).Value = "=SUM(M" & lStartSection & ":M" & lRow - 1 & ")"
        ws.Range("N" & lRow).Value = "=SUM(N" & lStartSection & ":N" & lRow - 1 & ")"

        'Set this back to zero so we know that we are no longer in a section
        lStartSection = 0
    End If

lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Adjusted the formula for columns M and N.